# android Unable to parse TLS packet header

Tags: java, android, kotlin, http, ssl

Есть функция http запросов:

```
internal class AsyncRequest : AsyncTask<String, Int, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: String?): String {
        var host = "https://192.168.0.22:8080"
        for (i in p0 ){
            host += i
        }
        val mURL = URL(host)
        with(mURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection) {
            requestMethod = "GET"
            if (responseCode == 200){
                access = 200
                BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream)).use {
                    val response = StringBuffer()
                    var inputLine = it.readLine()
                    while (inputLine != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine)
                        inputLine = it.readLine()
                    }
                    it.close()
                    responseBody = "$response"
                }
            }
        }
        return ""
    }
}
```

В манифесте прописаны:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Но при вызове функции вылетает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.a123, PID: 12051
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to parse TLS packet header
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:807)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at com.example.a123.utils.AsyncRequest.doInBackground(AsyncRequest.kt:21)
        at com.example.a123.utils.AsyncRequest.doInBackground(AsyncRequest.kt:12)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
```

Как исправить эту ошибку ?

Comment: Возможно, вы не настроили на самом деле шифрование трафика на локальном сервере для использования https протокола. Попробуйте использовать `http` протокол, разрешив его использование в манифесте.

Comment: А если `https` включено, тогда проблема в не валидном сертификате.